# Does installation of nvcc (nvidia-cuda-toolkit) affect my graphic driver?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, cuda

I have followed previous [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087361/gpu-emulator-for-cuda-programming-without-the-hardware) for emulation of `CUDA` on my laptop which does not have any `nvidia` graphic card at all.

The solution of `nvcc -deviceemu` on my ubuntu looks cool. However, my concern is that if I install `nvcc` does it disrupt my graphic by affecting my graphic driver? I avoid risk of coming up with black screen. Does `nvcc` affect my graphic in any way?